# How to POST to server / I keep getting a post 400 error

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm sure I'm missing something but I can't seem to figure out what it is. I'm trying to POST the dropdown menu but it doesn't show up in the console and I get a post 400 when I submit. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you <3

Sorry it's a lot of code but I'm still navigating through react and just need some help on this.
Also I have React, useState, and useEffect imported from "react" it's just not showing up on  the code

```
import axios from "axios";

function PostForm() {
  const url = "https://frontend-take-home.fetchrewards.com/form";
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    occupations: "",
    states: "",
  });

  const URL = "https://frontend-take-home.fetchrewards.com/form";
  const [occupations, setOccupation] = useState([]);
  const [states, setState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(function () {
    axios
      .get(URL)
      .then((data) => setOccupation(data.data.occupations))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    axios
      .get(URL)
      .then((data) => setState(data.data.states))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  function handle(e) {
    const newData = { ...data };
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
    setData(newData);
    console.log(newData);
  }
  function submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post(url, data).then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => submit(e)}>
        <label>Full Name</label>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
          id="name"
          value={data.name}
          placeholder="Full Name"
          type="text"
          name="name"
        />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
          id="email"
          value={data.email}
          placeholder="Email"
          type="text"
          name="email"
        />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
          id="password"
          value={data.password}
          placeholder="Password"
          type="password"
          name="password"
        />
        <div>
          <select>
            {occupations.map((occupation) => (
              <option
                key={occupation}
                id="occupation"
                name="occupations"
                placeholder="Occupation"
                onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
                value={data.occupations}
              >
                {occupation}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
          <select>
            {states.map((state) => (
              <option
                key={state.id}
                value={data.states}
                onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
              >
                {state.name}({state.abbreviation})
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PostForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be your server error which you are trying to request which means your code is correct , try to **provide the full error message** for more specific answer

Comment: This is not really an answer. It would be better as a comment.